# PdfMake getBase64 undefined - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdfmake

I created a function generated pdf that are using

```
   const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
    pdfDocGenerator.getBase64((pdfData) => {
      resolve({
        pdfData: `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfData}`,
        onlyData: pdfData,
      });
    });
```

the code **pdfDocGenerator.getBase64** saying its undefined but **pdfDocGenerator** is having a value.

my pdfDocGenerator console.
[image]

can someone help with this Im using new promise inside of generatepdf file and there's an index file that calling the generatedpdf

[image]

added information
[image]

what if I want created pdf and open with still not working blank
[image]

CODE REPRODUCE: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gw7c3h?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: what does ```createPdf``` look like? does it require an await?

Comment: I just follow the docs https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/methods/

Comment: I am suspecting if there is something wrong with the docDefinition object - perhaps it doesnt contain data expected by createPdf?
you can try http://pdfmake.org/playground.html# to test simple code first as given in this example https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/client-side/methods/#get-the-pdf-as-base64-data (using a sample docDefinition) and then replace with ur docDefinition (also, can u paste the text/JSON string of your docDefinition rather than the image (cant copy from the image)

Comment: Hi @gawkface I edit the information, I can send all the json file since that's to long content, But i try your suggestion still having the problem, I try to open the created pdf without doin the base 64 still having the problem.

Comment: I would recommend for you to share code and data via https://gist.github.com/ (you would create your own) (dont know if github/markdown has collapsed code blocks). Anyway, will post an answer because I think my earlier hunch was right when I look at the new data you posted

Comment: I try pdfmake.org/playground.html#  using the content, my data is right. will try to create a gist.github.com

Comment: Hi @gawkface kindly check https://gist.github.com/michaelVictoriaDev/732e870e8e6a9c034674a9c6d4cb53d4 :) the docDefinition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238582/discussion-between-mike-victoria-and-gawkface).

Comment: Weird thing happen when the content is array of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking the console.logs error in that way you can check what is the content problem in my case I just import the

```
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Comment: I kept seeing the Roboto fonts error too and that's why in my gist/playground you would see I included that too; but when you said you didnt see any console errors, I thought problem must have been something different. Anyway, its great that you finally solved it, you did well keeping at it for so long! You get to mark your own answer as the "Accepted solution"!

Comment: Thank you also @gawkface for getting solution done .. Cheers!